# Django sum values of from a for loop in template

Tags: django, templates

I want to show the sum for the values (cals, protein, carbs, etc) of multiple foods in a new table but have no idea how to do it in a django template.

Heres what the for loop displays

```
{% for food in meal.foods.all %}
                <div class='table-container'>
                    <table class='food-table'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Calories</th>
                                <th>Protein</th>
                                <th>Carbs</th>
                                <th>Fat</th>
                                <th>Sugar</th>
                                <th>Sodium</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ food.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ food.calories }}</td>
                                <td>{{ food.protein }}g</td>
                                <td>{{ food.carbs }}g</td>
                                <td>{{ food.fat }}g</td>
                                <td>{{ food.sugar }}g</td>
                                <td>{{ food.sodium }}mg</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

The new table would look like this but just display the totals.
[image: Models]

[image: View]

Comment: Can you provide the model and view? You can calculate these totals by running an aggregate query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I understand, you want the total protien, crab, .. of an specific meal.

An easy way to achieve this would be making new `property` in Models `Meal`.

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def get_total_protein(self):
        return sum([food.protien for food in self.foods.all()])

    @property
    def get_total_carbs(self):
        return sum([food.carbs for food in self.foods.all()])
    
    # and the same for fat, sugr..
```

then you can access it in your template. for example lets access them in table foot

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>{{ meal.get_total_proteins }}</th>
        <th>{{ meal.get_total_carbs }}</th>
        <th> ... </th>
        <th> ... </th>
        <th> ... </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. One thing however for anyone who might have the same question in the future. Since food is a ManyToMany field, it has to be: return sum([food.protein for food in self.foods.all()])   appreciate the help none the less!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by utilizing the `SUM()` function in SQL via the [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) function [Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#sum). Sample usage [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> from my_app.models import Food, Meal
>>>
>>> Food.objects.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Fries', 'calories': Decimal('150.00'), 'protein': Decimal('10.00')}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Burger', 'calories': Decimal('200.00'), 'protein': Decimal('13.00')}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Celery', 'calories': Decimal('30.00'), 'protein': Decimal('9.00')}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Coke', 'calories': Decimal('500.00'), 'protein': Decimal('22.00')}]>
>>>
>>> meal = Meal.objects.get(name='Snack')
>>> meal.foods.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Fries', 'calories': Decimal('150.00'), 'protein': Decimal('10.00')}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Burger', 'calories': Decimal('200.00'), 'protein': Decimal('13.00')}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Coke', 'calories': Decimal('500.00'), 'protein': Decimal('22.00')}]>
>>>
>>> meal.foods.aggregate(Sum('calories'), Sum('protein'))
{'calories__sum': Decimal('850'), 'protein__sum': Decimal('45')}
```

You can then just pass the dict result to your template for viewing.

Should there be changes with the meal, it would reflect upon calling `aggregate`.

```
>>> Food.objects.create(name='Chips', calories=80, protein=5)
<Food: Food object (5)>
>>> meal.foods.add(Food.objects.get(name='Chips'))
>>> meal.foods.aggregate(Sum('calories'), Sum('protein'))
{'calories__sum': Decimal('930'), 'protein__sum': Decimal('50')}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. But would this be updated whenever a user adds another food to a meal. I'm pretty new to SQL and Django.

Comment: The call to `aggregate` would query the database thus would always get the most updated data. I updated the answer to show this behavior.